# django_auth_ldap can't use populate_user signal

Tags: django-auth-ldap

Trying to use the populate_user signal to do some custom processing but no effect.

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django_auth_ldap.backend import populate_user, LDAPBackend


@receiver(populate_user, sender=LDAPBackend)
def ldap_auth_handler(user, ldap_user, **kwargs):
    """
        Create mailbox and create user with email
    """
    print("signal")
```

User gets populated, log below:

> search_s('ou=people,dc=example,dc=com', 2, '(mail=%(user)s)') returned
> 1 objects: uid=alice,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
> DEBUG:django_auth_ldap:search_s('ou=people,dc=example,dc=com', 2,
> '(mail=%(user)s)') returned 1 objects:
> uid=alice,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com Creating Django user
> alice@example.com DEBUG:django_auth_ldap:Creating Django user
> alice@example.com Populating Django user alice@example.com
> DEBUG:django_auth_ldap:Populating Django user alice@example.com

Answer (score 0):

Sorry didn't read the Django signals documentation properly, need to import the signals module in app_config. Also since I am using custom backend, had to replace it in the signal (not sure it is correct but works):

```
@receiver(populate_user, sender=CustomLDAPBackend)
```